# Combination of scripts: Python, PHP, Ruby, and Perl in single script in Python

Tags: php, python, ruby, python-2.7, perl

I have 8 scripts. I want to put them all into a single script, and the problem is that they are written in different languages:

- PHP
- Ruby
- Perl
- Python

But the final one should be in Python.

I want to do this without the need to rewrite all of them in Python.

Is there a way to do this?

The scripts accept an input `.txt` file as a command line argument, and generate an output `.txt` file.

Comment: Have you tried to write a shell script?

Comment: i know lel bit about sh but how do i tried to use a shell script?

Comment: It depends. For example, on a GNU/Linux platform one of the best shells is [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). In simplest case, a shell script looks like a list of commands. If you want to invoke the scripts from a Python script, then you should probably use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: I understand the down vote, because you haven't posted what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a couple of scripts each accepting a file path as the first argument:

*script.php*

```
<?php
$input_file = $argv[1] ?? 'default-input-file';
echo $input_file, PHP_EOL;
```

*script.pl*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = $ARGV[0] // 'default-input-file';
print "$input_file\n";
```

In Python you can call them by means of [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
#/usr/bin/env python2
import os.path
import sys
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s input-file" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

input_file = sys.argv[1]

if not os.path.isfile(input_file):
    sys.stderr.write("%s is not a file" % input_file)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    output = check_output(['php', './script.php', input_file], stderr=STDOUT)
    print "PHP: %s" % output

    output = check_output(['perl', './script.pl', input_file], stderr=STDOUT)
    print "Perl: %s" % output
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Execution failed: ", e
```

You might want to wrap the commands into a shell script. For example, a [`Bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script might look like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -

if ! php ./script.php "$@" ; then
  echo >&2 "php command failed"
fi

if ! perl ./script.pl "$@" ; then
  echo >&2 "perl command failed"
fi
```

The `$@` variable represents all the command line arguments passed to the script. The `if` statements check if the commands finished successfully. The `echo >&2` command prints a string to the standard error descriptor. Having the shell wrapper you might call a single subprocess in Python:

```
try:
    output = check_output(['./call-scripts.sh', input_file])
    print output
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Execution failed: ", e
```